# What is the difference between 'bash command' and 'bash -c command'?

Tags: bash, shell

I found some difference in between running command and script in bash:

1. `bash /bin/ls` - not working
2. `bash -c /bin/ls` - working
3. `bash ./my_script.sh` - working
4. `bash -c ./my_script.sh` - working

Without `-c` option, can bash not get general command? Why does bash work like this?

Comment: Run a file as script vs run the CLI argument as script.

Comment: Sorry. General commands mean really external commands which installed /bin, /usr/bin, /sbin/~~~ extra.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between 'bash command' and 'bash -c command'?

`bash command` *interprets* the *content* of the file `command` as a bash script and executes its content.

`bash -c command` *interprets* the *string* argument `command` as a bash script and executes its content.

The visible difference would be in files in other languages with different interpreters. `iotop` is a program in python, `bash /bin/iotop` will give you a syntax error, as it interprets the content of the file `/bin/iotop` as a bash script. `bash -c /bin/iotop` will interpret the string `/bin/iotop` as a script, `/bin/iotop` is a command to execute the binary `/bin/iotop`, which bash will do.

`bash command` is a typical way to "force" using bash interpreter. In case `./my_script.sh` has no executable permissions, `bash ./my_script.sh` will execute the content of the file, whereas `bash -c ./my_script.sh` (or just `./my_script.sh` in an open shell) will fail.

> Why does bash work like this?

There is no specific answer to that question. Bash "works like this" most probably because SysV sh design "worked like this", which is because the author designed it that way.

Comment: I think "it works like this" because this is normal. If you type "firefox file", firefox will assume that "file" is an HTML document. And "bash ls" will assume that "ls" is a "bash file" (script).

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I was trying to go up other tree. I am cleared.  'content' vs 'string'